# Solve Numerical Equation

Tags: equation-solving, precision-and-accuracy, approximation

I want to find $x\in \ \mathbb{Q} $ such that the first ten digits of $ x \pi $ are `1.234567890`.

I tried:

```
Solve[N[x*Pi, 10] = 1.234567890, x, Rationals]
```

But *Mathematica* returns:

> Set::write: Tag Times in N[[Pi] x,{10.,[Infinity]}] is Protected. >>
>   Solve::naqs: 1.23456789` is not a quantified system of equations and
>   inequalities. >>

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Try changing the `=` to a `==`

Comment: Ah you are right. Also the answer will be disappointing for it'll just calculate  the solution 1.234567890/pi and then give a accurate enough decimal approximation of that. Sorry that was a bad question. Thanks! It was a substitute question for something I tried to solve, but it turns out it isn't a good substitute.

Comment: The original problem is similar though had a more difficult expression as the argument of N[...,10] and it gives the error: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the \
system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present \
in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact \
input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[x]

x = x /. Solve[x*Pi == 1.234567890, x][[1]] // Rationalize[#, 0] &

(*  912525135/2322093652  *)

x*Pi // N[#, 10] &

(*  1.234567890  *)
```